# Jquery - BBC +/- buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as my boss loves the bbc site (www.bbc.com), does anyone have any suggestions for creating the functionality for controlling how many items are in the list using the plus and minus buttons? When clicking plus it will add more items, when clicking minus it wil remove the bottom item.

It looks like this is done using Jquery, anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what plus/ minus buttons are you talking about?

Comment: @hunter: Check http://www.bbc.co.uk/ - and then I'm sure he means the `+`/`-` near "More Top Stories".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BBC loads all the items and just marks some of them as hidden using a `.hide` CSS class. It's not very sophisticated. So your jQuery will go something like:

**Plus**

`$("#myDiv li.hide:first").removeClass("hide");`

**Minus**

`$("#myDiv li:not(.hide):last").addClass("hide");`